# Is there a performant, atomic way to "dequeue" from a table and see if it is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table to store state for an SQS queue that is accessed from multiple processes. The way that it works now is that all messages in the queue are added to the table. Each time a message from the queue is dequeued, it is also deleted from the table. When the table/queue become empty, some finalization actions need to be run. The way that it is currently implemented is this:

```
-- dequeue (2 statements so that we can use the primary index for the delete - was seeing a lot of deadlocking otherwise)
BEGIN;
SELECT id FROM messages WHERE messageKey = 'message_key' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = 'auto_inc_id';
COMMIT;

-- check if it was the last one (shared lock so we know that nobody is currently deleting a message - select count(*) was also causing deadlocks due to locking so many rows)
SELECT * FROM messages LIMIT 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;

-- perform finalization if no records returned
```

Unfortunately it seems that these statements are causing some contention with one another which is causing slowness in the application - is there an obvious way to do it that is still atomic but requires fewer statements or transactions?

The table is pretty simple, but I'll include it if anybody is curious

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `messageKey` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT @id := id FROM ... FOR UPDATE;
    IF (@id IS NOT NULL) THEN
        DELETE ... WHERE id = @id;
    END IF;
COMMIT;
```

Then proceed to use @id.

There is a flaw in the logic:  If the server crashes before you finish 'using' @id, there is no recovery.

If you want to discuss fixing that flaw, first answer this question:  If you "use" @id twice, will harm be done?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! However I'm not sure how this helps with knowing if the table is empty once the message is removed; perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: When the table is empty, `SELECT` will set `@id:=NULL`.  Then `WHERE id=NULL` will fail, so the `DELETE` won't delete anything.  Hence, the `IF` is optional.  The `COMMIT` is still necessary -- to balance the `BEGIN`.